# Nest-API Thermostat device not showing in REST request

Tags: ios, rest, nest-api

I'm using Chrome's Postman extension to determine why the NestDK iOS app isn't showing the thermostat after we sign in and decided to try a REST request to see what was returned.  I input https://developer-api.nest.com?auth= into the Postman interface and do a GET.
I get back the response below, with a thermostat defined in the structures data element, but there is no devices data element.  I know the device is connected because when I change from home to away, the 'away' setting is modified. Why are there no devices?

```
{
    "structures": {
        "<structure_id>": {
            "name": "Home",
            "country_code": "US",
            "time_zone": "America/New_York",
            "away": "away",
            "thermostats": [
                "<thermometer_id>"
            ],
            "structure_id": "<structure_id>"
        }
    },
    "metadata": {
        "access_token": "<accessToken>",
        "client_version": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your client permissions. Make sure that you have either Thermostat read or Thermostat read/write selected.

[Available Permissions](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/permissions-overview#available-permissions)

Comment: This is true.  I was under the impression that I needed to get to the thermostat level to get the Away process.  Our client wasn't set up to get this, but we didn't need it.  Thanks!